# @Html.ActionLink() routing to incorrect controller

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using following ActionLink method:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Manage User Branch", "mngBranchUser", "branchUser", new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```

to link to `"mngBranchUser"` method in `"branchUser"` controller but it is actually routing to `"mngBranchUser"` method in `"Home"` controller (which is the *global* controller of-course.) with **URL** as: `http://localhost:57852/Home/mngBranchUser?Length=10`. 
HTML generated by the given line of code is:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="/Home/mngBranchUser?Length=10">Manage User Branch</a>
```

when the desired HTML is:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="/branchUser/mngBranchUser?Length=10">Manage User Branch</a>
```

Also, if I change from:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Manage User Branch", "mngBranchUser", "branchUser", new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```

to

```
@Html.ActionLink("Manage User Branch", "mngBranchUser", "branchUser" })
```

I successfully get the desired output correct. But I need `new { @class = "btn btn-default"` part of the code for formatting reasons. Can someone please guide. Thank you.

Comment: Area there areas involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no overloaded method as `ActionLink(HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object)` thus proper URL is not generated.

So [`ActionLink Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, Object)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object%29) is applied and 3rd argument is treated as `routeValue`

> routeValues
>
> > An object that contains the parameters for a route. The parameters are retrieved through reflection by examining the properties of the object. The object is typically created by using object initializer syntax.

So it's creating length based on property of string literal `branchUser` i.e. length(10)

You can use [`LinkExtensions.ActionLink Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object, Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

```
@Html.ActionLink("Manage User Branch", "mngBranchUser", "branchUser", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```

Answer (score 3):

Your using the wrong overload of `ActionLink()` and it needs to be

```
@Html.ActionLink("Manage User Branch", "mngBranchUser", "branchUser", null, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
```

Your [current overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.LinkExtensions.ActionLink%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper,System.String,System.String,System.Object,System.Object%29) is adding the 3rd parameter as the route values (and "branchUser" contains 10 characters so its add `length="10"` because `length` is the only property of `string`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
<a href="@Url.Action("mngBranchUser","branchUser",new{ })" class="btn btn-default" >Manage User Branch</a>
```